# Writing to Access table fails when an Excel workbook has an open connection to it

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to make a windows form app, that stores information in an access database which can then be viewed in Excel.

I have got it to write to the database, and it workes fine until I try to imort the data to Excel. I then get the error: "operation must be an updateble query"

This seems to have something to do with the database beeing imported to Excel, somehow.

Does anyone know what this is, and what can be done?

The reason I need to view the data in excel has do do with my very conservative and anti-access colleagues, who are used to it.

Here is the code i am trying:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\espen\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ProjectName\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        connection.Open()
        Dim sqlString As String = "INSERT INTO TableName ([column1], [column2]) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        Using command As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlString, connection)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

        connection.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you are showing is for the write to Access, which you say works fine.  Can you show the lines which are causing a problem?  The `operation must use an updatable query` error message indicates a problem with an UPDATE/INSERT in Access rather than with the retrieval of data to Excel

Comment: The line that is troublesom is "command.ExecuteNonQuery()"
As long as the Excell document which imports data from the database is open, I get an unhandled OleDbExeption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue. It appears to be caused by the default settings used when Excel creates a connection to an Access database. The default connection string includes the option

```
Mode=Share Deny Write;
```

so when Excel has the connection open no other process can write to the Access database.

The following fix seems to work for me:

In Excel, click the "Connections" button on the "Data" tab of the ribbon. With the appropriate connection selected in the list, click the "Properties..." button. On the "Definition" tab, edit the "Connection string" to use

```
Mode=Share Deny None;
```

as shown here:

[image: ShareDenyNone.png]

Save the changes, then close and re-open the Excel workbook.